# How to get total of measures for a particular granularity in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables for my book inventory. Incoming 'Buy' table and outgoing 'Sales'. There are 2 sources for Incoming, Buy list, and Others, based on a per shipment basis. And Sales has sale records for each book for a given order.
By rule, any sale made in a period should be first debited from Others column from the 'Buy' table count and the rest should be treated as the Buylist sale. (ed. For Book A, we bought 5 books from 'Buylist' and 5 from 'Other' and were able to Sale 7 books in the month of May; I will conclude that we sold 5 books from others, 2 books from 'Buylist,' irrespective of when they were bought)
My schema looks like this.

[image: Schema]

I created a Bookkey table as PWI was not allowing many to many connection between Buy and Sales. I created 2 measures to calculate the BuyBack sales and Excess inventory left from Buyback.

```
BuyList Sales =
IF (
    ( SUM ( Sales[Sales] ) - SUM ( Buy[Others] ) ) > 0,
    IF (
        ( SUM ( Sales[Sales] ) - SUM ( Buy[Others] ) - SUM ( Buy[BuyList] ) ) >= 0,
        SUM ( Buy[BuyList] ),
        SUM ( Sales[Sales] ) - SUM ( Buy[Others] )
    ),
    0
)
```

and

```
BuyList Excess = SUM( Buy[BuyList] ) - [BuyList Sales]
```

I am getting the correct results in the rows on the BookKey granularity, but the Totals are not correct as it is Calculated on the entire data set. Is there any other way of getting the Total while also be able to control the period.[image]

Can anyone help me get the correct Total amount?

Comment: What value are you expecting?

Comment: I am looking for the Total of the numbers I see at the granularity level. E.g. The total of the column BuyList Sale to be 202+69+48+45+176... and for BuyList Excess as 619+381+350+333+328..

Comment: I think you may find the `SUMX(VALUES(...),...)` pattern useful. See [here](https://powerpivotpro.com/2014/08/sumx-of-if-a-perfect-blend-of-simple-sophisticated/) and [here](https://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/) for examples.

Comment: I tried it but it didnt work. I replaced all the SUM with SUMX in the original formula but it gave different numbers for the rows itself.